# "TypeError: a float is required" occurred when using urllib2

Tags: python, twitter

I was following the [twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) of issuing application-only requests.
Error occurred when doing *Step 2: Obtain a bearer token*. I'm not familiar with the details of these modules in traceback, could anyone tell me how to make the code work?

Here is my code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, base64

consumer_key = 'KmdCpWGtKEtQ0EdZyQCEZGmcX'
consumer_secret = 'B3I0RcG8vsCC1Y4LBIHIlNvm2NrSB9smlPovYnKYjCyUoNBcMd'
consumer_key_secret = urllib.quote(consumer_key) + ':' + urllib.quote(consumer_secret)
token = base64.b64encode(consumer_key_secret)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credenials'}

resp = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', urllib.urlencode(data), headers)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_only_auth.py", line 12, in <module>
    resp = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', urllib.urlencode(data), headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1157, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 559, in create_connection
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: Something has mucked up your `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` value, it appears. What does `import socket; print repr(socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)` produce?

Comment: If the answer is `<object object at 0x.....>`, then what does `print socket.create_connection.func_defaults[0]` print? The two outputs should match.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, they match.

Comment: Did you call [`urllib2.install_opener()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.install_opener) at any point?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I didn't. Should I?

Comment: No, just trying to trace all possibilities here. Next is `urllib2.OpenerDirector.open.func_defaults[1]`; it should be the same object as `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Running out of ideas then; this will require a debugging session (`import pdb; pdb.run("urllib2.urlopen('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', urllib.urlencode(data), headers)"`) and careful checking of what happens in the `socket` module.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient, reading [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) now :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The urlopen function uses this format:  urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])

In your code you are giving the headers to urlopen as the timeout value which causes you to get the TypeError.

The headers should be added by creating the request with the urllib2.Request() function. For example:

```
req = urllib2.Request('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', urllib.urlencode(data), headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```