# “TypeError: a float is required” occurred when using websocket

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, urllib2

I'm running into the `TypeError: a float is required` when i try creating a connection using `websocket.create_connection`

```
full_url = "wss://myurl:443/abc/def/ghi?id=asdf3nnasdfj34nasdf23"
header_conn = dict()
header_conn['Authorization'] = "Auth service=<my authorization token goes here>"  

ws = websocket.create_connection(full_url, header_conn)
```

The exception that is shown to me is:

```
  File "try.py", line 268, in <module>
    ws = websocket.create_connection(full_url, headers_conn1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 487, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 211, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 71, in connect
    sock = _open_socket(addrinfo_list, options.sockopt, options.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 106, in _open_socket
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: a float is required
```

Any idea what i'm missing? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710894/typeerror-a-float-is-required-occurred-when-using-urllib2) link but i wasn't sure how to apply the same solution in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`websocket.create_connection`](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/master/websocket/_core.py#L436) seems to take a `timeout` value as a second argument. In your case, `header_conn` is interpreted as the `timeout` argument.

Try with

```
ws = websocket.create_connection(full_url, header=header_conn)
```